# Custom Stripe Checkout with Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, stripe-payments

I'm trying to figure out how to set up custom checkout integration with Stripe on my Flask web app.

I copied the code found in the Stripe documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) into the bottom of my HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
  <form role="form" id = "myForm" action="{{ url_for('charge')}}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 button-field" style = "text-align: center;">
              <button type="confirm" id = 'confirm' onclick = "runStripe('https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js')" class="btn btn-default btn-responsive btn-lg">Confirm Order</button>
            </div>
          </div>  
      <script>
        var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: "{{ key }}",
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function(token) {
              $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
              $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
              $("#myForm").submit();
          }
        });

        document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          // Open Checkout with further options:
          handler.open({
            name: 'Checkout',
            description: "",
            amount: {{ amount }}
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });

        // Close Checkout on page navigation:
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
          handler.close();
        });
      </script>
      <script>
      document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
    </script>
</form>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, although the Stripe checkout screen will pop up, it fails to send a POST request to my server. I'm fairly certain that this is because my function(token) is incorrect. However, I'm not too good with Javascript, so I'm lost as to what to do here. Any suggestions as to how I can send the token to my Flask server would be greatly appreciated. For reference, here's my backend:

```
@app.route('/charge', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def charge():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email = session['user'],
                source = request.form['stripeToken']
            )

            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                customer = customer.id,
                amount = session['amount'],
                currency = 'usd',
                description = 'Payment'
            )
            orders = mongo.db.orders
            has_ordered = orders.find_one({'_id': session['user']})
            if has_ordered:
                orders.update({'_id': session['user']},
                                {'$set':
                                    {'name': request.form['name'],
                                     'dorm': request.form['dorm']}})
            else:
                orders.insert({'_id': session['user'],
                                'name': request.form['name'],
                                'dorm': request.form['dorm']})
            for key, value in (session['customer']).iteritems():
                has_ordered = orders.find_one({'_id': session['user'], str(key): {'$exists': True}})
                total = int(value)
                if has_ordered:
                    total += int(has_ordered[key])
                orders.update({'_id': session['user']},
                                {'$set':
                                     {key: total}})
            content = render_template('message.html', ordered = True)
            send_mail('Your Order Summary', content, session['user'], True)
            session['customer'] = {}
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        try:
            if g.user:
                return render_template('charge.html', 
                                        key = stripe_keys['publishable_key'],
                                        amount = session['amount'],
                                        tax = session['tax'],
                                        subtotal = session['subtotal'],
                                        months = 2 * deliveries_remaining())
        except KeyError:
            return redirect(url_for('shop'))
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

If someone could provide me with the code to use for the function(token) I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser console log to see whether it recognises the jquery code in your token. When I ran this code the console returned `$ is not defined`.

Try initializing jquery within the token like so:

```
          var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: "{{ stripe_key }}",
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function(token) {
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
            $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
            $("#payment_form").submit();
            })
          }
        });
```

And add this script above the container div:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Refer to this page if you want to learn more: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: How did you go @M. Ying? Let me know if this worked out for you